# How do I add class tag to this rails link_to tag in slim?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I wanted to add class name 'button' to this following tag.

```
= link_to 'Upload data', new_raw_datum_path if logged_in?
```

So I tried this,

```
= link_to 'Upload data', new_raw_datum_path if logged_in?, class: 'button'
```

but it gave me back this error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...w_raw_datum_path if logged_in?, class: 'button'), true, "\n ...
...
```

My way of adding a class name worked fine in other pages but not this page.
(This is a link in my navigation)

How could I add them in slim???
Thank you for your time.
                              ^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
= link_to 'Upload data', new_raw_datum_path, class: 'button' if logged_in?
```

Comment: THX! May I ask why it should be in that order?

Comment: `class: 'button'` is part of the arguments of link_to and, if the parentheses were not omitted, it would read `= link_to('Upload data', new_raw_datum_path, class: 'button') if logged_in?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) of rails actionview:

```
= link_to_if(logged_in?, "Login", new_raw_datum_path, class: 'button') do
    link_to 'Upload data', new_raw_datum_path
  end
```